# Freemarker: reload template using custom function

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

i want to use freemarker with templates from database. templates will change sometimes. i would like to create a `Function<String, String>` that takes a template name and return current template from database.

How can i make freemarker considers templates stale after x minutes and just calls my function every time it needs new version of template? or maybe some other templating provides such functionality out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a configuration setting called `template_update_delay`, or with Java API `Configuration.setTemplateUpdateDelayMilliseconds(long)`. This decides how often FreeMarker checks if a template cache entry is stale. (It only does that when you require the template, and its cache entry is older than that.) I guess you should simply rely on that.

There's also `Configuration.removeTemplateFromCache`, in case you are notified about template changes.

Comment: and how to plug in the template supplier function that's triggered every time newer template should be loaded? the only way is to provide custom template loader?

Comment: Yes, you do that via a custom `TemplateLoader`.